# Function Output_Assignment_Variable

Tags: python

I´m a begginer in Python and I would like to use the output of a function into another function, the problem is when a assign the output of the function it automatically runs again.

```
def my_function():
    print("Don´t print this")
    variable1 = 5
    return variable1

variable2 = my_function()
print(variable2)
```

The output is:
Don´t print this ---> This should not appear
5 ----> I just want to print this value

Is there any manner to dont run all the function statements just want to assign the output of the function to a variable and print?

Comment: The purpose of a function is to encapsulate a block of code to be run potentially multiple times. You cannot simply exclude lines from running from a function. If you don't want that print to run, I wouldn't include it in the function. You could also pass in a boolean, and only print if that boolean is True, but that's generally regarded as poor practice. You could also use a method of swallowing all text sent to the STDOUT by overwriting STDOUT with a dummy file, but I don't think that's great practice either if you have control over the code already.

Comment: Also, you say that the function runs again, but in your code it only runs once, at the `variable = my_function()` line.  The `def my_function()` block just defines the function.